# Using forms inside modals

Tags: forms, modal-windows

I'm a developer so maybe this question is very basic. Is it a good practice to use forms inside modals with many inputs (more than 5 inputs including date-pickers, text inputs, textarea...)?. I am developing a web aplication and I'm not sure what to use for creating data: new pages or modals.
Thanks to everyone

Comment: Hi @xespinos, there are several questions with this topic. Type "form modal" at the search field to find them. [Duplicate 2](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/75338/115107) , [Duplicate 3](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/31259/115107)...

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a real limit on the number of inputs for a modal window form, but there are other considerations:

1. Should the user be prevented from working on any other tasks? If so, that's a modal.
2. Does the user need to reference anything else on the page while working on the form? If so, you might consider a sheet.
3. If the user accidentally closes the modal by clicking outside of the window, will they lose a lot of work? If so, consider a sheet or a page.
4. Does your form combine a lot of different tasks, rather than providing one thing for the user to do? If so, consider making that a page.